# how to pass a hidden value using post with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want only registered users to vote. I do not want to change all my codes. Easiest way to do for me now is set something to true if user logged in and pass that in the hidden field.

How can i pass a hidden value on here?

This is what i have got so far

```
$(function() {

$(".vote").click(function() 
{

var name = $(this).attr("name");
var id = $(this).attr("id");

var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
var parent = $(this);


if(name=='up')
{

$(this).fadeIn(200).html('<img src="dot.gif" align="absmiddle">');
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "up_vote.php",
   data: dataString,
   cache: false,

   success: function(html)
   {
    parent.html(html);

  }  });

}

return false;
    });

});
```

---

```
  <div class="box1">
    <div class="up"><a href="" class="vote" name="up" id="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['plus'].'</a></div>
  </div>
```

**up_vote.php**

```
if($_POST['id'])
{

$id=$_POST['id'];
.
.
. 
}
```

Comment: Why not have the php do the checking and disable voting by not echoing the vote <a hrefs> if the user isn't logged in?

Comment: i have to change too many codes. I can not just disable voting.

Comment: Oh, the joys of spaghetti-code [PHP] :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add your hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="loggedIn" value="whatever" />
```

Set up variable

```
var id = $(this).attr("id");
var loggedIn = $("#loggedIn").val(); //will be the value of loggedIn
```

Change this line in $.ajax()

```
data: {loggedIn: loggedIn, id: id}
```

Comment: I agree with bdares that this is the wrong approach, but it will work.

Answer (score 8):

Wrong approach.  Javascript is executed on the client side.  You never trust the client, because the client is controlled by the user.  Use the session, which is stored server-side.

(What will keep the user from copy+pasting the page code, modifying it, and executing it?)

Comment: Or using firebug or some other javascript debugger and changing the value of the hidden field before submitting it.

Answer (score 0):

simply by appending the hidden field to the dataString

```
dataString += 'foo=bar'
```